# Container width smaller than slider width, hide overflow?

Tags: css

See screenshot here: http://s12.postimage.org/wvt2xt365/overflow.png

My container width is 1000px and slider width is 1400px. How do I have it so the overflow is just set to the container width, not the slider width?

So if a user has a browser size of 1200px, there wouldn't be any scrollbars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overflow has a number of options. You can force an object to have "hidden" overflow thus:

```
#container 
{
width:1000px;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Please note that this means that the overflow is clipped, and the rest of the content will be invisible... which is, I presume, what you're asking for?

Comment: not really as overflow:hidden on the container will force the slider 1400px to be clipped.

Comment: Ah worked it out with your help!

    <div id="header-image">
     <div id="header-image-wrap">
     <div id="header-images">
       <img src="feature1.jpg" />
       <img src="feature2.jpg" />
            <img src="feature3.jpg" />
     </div>
     </div>
    </div>

Then CSS:

    #header-image {position:absolute;width:1200px;left:50%;margin-left:-600px;min-width:1000px}
    #header-image-wrap {width:1200px;overflow:hidden;}
    #header-images {width:7000px;}

Answer (score 1):

It is an interesting question. You can place the slider inside another container of width 100% and hide overflow.

Is this what you are looking for or do you want to resize the slider itself till 1400px? In this case you should use media queries.